# Error trying to add to the navigation url of a hyperlinkfield

Tags: vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

Am trying to add to the navigation url in a hyperlink field.

I have 5 columns on my gridview, the last being

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="vID" 
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Page2.aspx?field={0}" HeaderText="send" 
            Text="send"></asp:HyperLinkField>
```

and the code behind to add to it

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    Dim hk As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(4).Controls(0), HyperLink)
    hk.NavigateUrl += "&TN=table1"

End Sub
```

I had it working yesterday, but must have accidentally deleted the code, and I cant find where am going wrong here, I get an error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the [`RowType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx), otherwise you're looking for the `HyperLink` also in the header.

VB

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs )
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim link = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(4).Controls(0), HyperLink)
        link.NavigateUrl &= "&TN=table1"
    End If
End Sub
```

C#

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
        link.NavigateUrl += "&TN=table1";
    {
}
```